# Do the paths of a deformation retraction cover the boundary?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $A$ be a compact set in $R^n$, $U$ its open neighbourhood, and $H:U\times I \to U$ a strong deformation retraction of $U$ onto $A$. It seems plausible that for any point $a\in\partial A$ there exists $x\in U\setminus A$ and $t\in I$ such that $H(x,t)=a$. Is it really true, and why?

(I mean any compact subset $A\subset R^n$ and any open set $U$, $A\subset U\subset R^n$.)

Comment: any compact set? or a submanifold? what do you mean by *its* neighborhood?